# Guava ListenableFuture allAsList returns all content seen so far from get

Tags: java, guava

I was wondering if there is any util for `ListenableFuture` that works like `allAsList` but if you call `get(50, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)` returns all that have completed.

Comment: How would you implement such a thing?  (I don't know if it's possible or not, but there's nothing magical in `Futures` -- if it's there, you could've implemented it yourself.)

Comment: How I was planning to do this was to take the code for allAsList and override get(int, TimeUnit) that when it times out to return the value's list.  It feels like a hacky solution so was hoping there would be something else.  I have had to do the same thing before in another project and used a countdown latch to solve this.  Each callback wrote to a list and if await timed out, then cancel all remaining futures and return the values list.

Comment: So I forked CombinedFuture and overrided get.  It feels very hacky and not tested, but this was I am looking for: https://gist.github.com/dcapwell/5492453

Comment: It strikes me that it's really not the best idea to do this as a fork of `CombinedFuture`, but rather to start from scratch.  In particular, I would always expect `Future.get(time, unit)` to either return the same result that `Future.get()` would return, or to throw a TimeoutException.

Comment: you are right, overriding get is not the best idea.  I like ListenableFuture so would it be better to have a new class that implements it and has a method that works like this?

Comment: Here's one possibility: For each `ListenableFuture`, attach a `FutureCallback` that adds its result to a `Queue`. Call `Queues.drain` on it. (We might one day add a class that does this for you. It's mainly a matter of figuring out what other features the class would support so that we can get the API right.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there might be in the future as I think the answer resides [there](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1146&thanks=1146&ts=1347504235) as discussed in this related question too:
[ListenableFuture, FutureCallback and timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380726/listenablefuture-futurecallback-and-timeouts)

Basically instead of having a special kind of Futures#allAsList(), you could add a callback with timeout on  all of your futures and use Futures#successfulAsList() over them. Thus, every future that times out, would fail with a TimeoutException and Futures#successfulAsList() would return only the successful ones, i.e. not those that failed with any kind of exception (including TimeoutException).

Unfortunately, this is not yet implemented in guava (see the first link to guava's tracker issue) but has been accepted at least as a valid request.