# AsyncRestTemplate ListenableFuture<T> Callback + Timeout

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have configured an AsyncRestTemplate like this, here just an illustration to show that I am using an *HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory* with *connectTimeout* and *readTimeout* being initialized with values - using Spring 4.0.8 RELEASE:

```
    <bean id="myAsynchRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="httpAsyncClient" ref="myCloseableHttpAsynchClient"></property>
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="444"></property>
        <property name="readTimeout" value="555"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAsynchRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="myAsynchRequestFactory"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I also have configured a *RequestConfig* as the spring code suggests that the former method is deprecated, so I added it like this:

```
<bean id="myRequestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
    <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="555"></property>
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="400"></property>
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="555"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="myRequestConfig" factory-bean="myRequestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build">
</bean>

<bean id="myHttpAsyncClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder">
    <property name="connectionManager" ref="myHttpAsyncConnectionManager"></property>
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="myRequestConfig"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="myHttpAsyncClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder">
    <property name="connectionManager" ref="myHttpAsyncConnectionManager"></property>
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="myRequestConfig"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="myCloseableHttpAsynchClient" factory-bean="myHttpAsyncClientBuilder" factory-method="build">
</bean>
```

Now I am using the AsyncRestTemplate together with its *addCallback()* method like this (as illustration):

```
  response = myAsynchRestTemplate.getForEntity( ... );
  response.addCallback(new org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<?>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<?> result) {
                        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                        System.out.println("FAILURE")
                    }
                }
```

I would expect that onSuccess(...) is never called when the Service takes more than 555ms to reply. But that does not happen. Even if my service fakes a delay of let's say 5000ms, the onSuccess method will be called no matter what.

I have searched the web for possible solutions to add some kind of timeout to a callback, but didn't find anything appropriate. I tried to read cross the org.springframework.util.concurrent.* code in any versions since 4.0 but didn't yet find anything that would prevent the registered callback from execution.

I already have seen the following Stackoverflow Questions:

[How to cancel AsyncRestTemplate HTTP request if they are taking too much time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380653/how-to-cancel-asyncresttemplate-http-request-if-they-are-taking-too-much-time) This one suggests that the timeout should work

[ListenableFuture, FutureCallback and timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380726/listenablefuture-futurecallback-and-timeouts) This one is using some Google Guava example, but I am using org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Does anybody have some solution for this problem?

**UPDATE**

I have found the root cause why this does not work...

The **HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory** does not take the RequestConfig I have provided. Instead, it is always null and such beeing recreated as RequestConfig.DEFAULT. This happens here:

From HttpComponentesAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory:

```
@Override
public AsyncClientHttpRequest createAsyncRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
    HttpAsyncClient asyncClient = getHttpAsyncClient();
    startAsyncClient();
    HttpUriRequest httpRequest = createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
    postProcessHttpRequest(httpRequest);



    /** HERE: It tries to create a HttpContext **/
    HttpContext context = createHttpContext(httpMethod, uri);




    if (context == null) {
        context = HttpClientContext.create();
    }
    // Request configuration not set in the context
    if (context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG) == null) {
        // Use request configuration given by the user, when available
        RequestConfig config = null;
        if (httpRequest instanceof Configurable) {
            config = ((Configurable) httpRequest).getConfig();
        }
        if (config == null) {
            config = RequestConfig.DEFAULT;
        }
        context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG, config);
    }
    return new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequest(asyncClient, httpRequest, context);
}
```

But the method createHttpContext(httpMethod, uri) always returns null:

```
/**
 * Template methods that creates a {@link HttpContext} for the given HTTP method and URI.
 * <p>The default implementation returns {@code null}.
 * @param httpMethod the HTTP method
 * @param uri the URI
 * @return the http context
 */
protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
    return null;
}
```

Thus, the HttpContext is recreated and gets a **RequestConfig.DEFAULT** attached.

Now **compare** this **with the non-Asynch** Version, **HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory**. *This one recreates a RequestConfig with Timeouts:*

```
@Override
public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = (CloseableHttpClient) getHttpClient();
    Assert.state(client != null, "Synchronous execution requires an HttpClient to be set");
    HttpUriRequest httpRequest = createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
    postProcessHttpRequest(httpRequest);
    HttpContext context = createHttpContext(httpMethod, uri);
    if (context == null) {
        context = HttpClientContext.create();
    }
    // Request configuration not set in the context
    if (context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG) == null) {
        // Use request configuration given by the user, when available
        RequestConfig config = null;
        if (httpRequest instanceof Configurable) {
            config = ((Configurable) httpRequest).getConfig();
        }
        if (config == null) {




            /** LOOK HERE - THE SYNC WORLD HAS THIS WORKAROUND */
            if (this.socketTimeout > 0 || this.connectTimeout > 0) {
                config = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(this.connectTimeout)
                        .setSocketTimeout(this.socketTimeout)
                        .build();
            }



            else {
                config = RequestConfig.DEFAULT;
            }
        }
        context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG, config);
    }
    if (this.bufferRequestBody) {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest(client, httpRequest, context);
    }
    else {
        return new HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest(client, httpRequest, context);
    }
}
```

When I am using a **SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory** instead the timeouts I configure are taken and rather than *onSuccess(...)*, the *onFailure(...)* method is called with a *SocketTimeoutException*

This is totally puzzling - maybe anyone can give a hint why the HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory is implemented as is?

Is there any example of the proper use of the RequestConfig Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is discussed in

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12540

There is a solution ahead in Spring 4.3 (current Spring is 4.2), and the solution for the time beeing is to subclass HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory and @Override the getHttpContext method.